# Требование уникального имени сущности в доменной логике

Tags: c#, архитектура, repository

Когда пишешь приложения начиная мыслить от базы, а не от доменной логики – многие вещи кажутся простыми и понятными. Вот допустим, некоторая сущность в проекте DataAccess:

```
public class Brand
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

И я всё понимаю: первичный ключ ID, обязательное поле Name, максимум nvarchar(50), все записи в таблице уникальны.

А когда начинаешь то же самое думать в терминах "сначала продумай доменную логику" начинаются вопросы.

Вот например, я начал то же самое проектирование от домена и в проекте Domain завёл класс:

```
public class Brand
{
    public Brand(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

И сразу задумался над двумя вещами:

- Как мне указать, что объекты должны иметь уникальные имена?
- Как мне проверить в unit-тестах для доменного проекта соблюдение этого условия?

Возможно ли такое вообще в принципе?

Когда у нас есть набор/множество объектов, то они не могут находиться в пустоте, а только в каком-то хранилище (я не в терминах слоя хранения употребляю это слово).

Например, можно хранить в List'е или Array'е — но лучше всего хранить это в Dictionary с ключом Name (условие уникальности обеспечится автоматом).

(Правда, в этом случае так же есть проблемы: непонятно, как быть если у нас должно быть два и более уникальных полей на одном объекте.)

Тем не менее, вот ещё какие дополнительно вопросы возникают:

- Можно ли вообще на уровне домена требовать уникальности полей (и нужно ли)? Или эти требования возможны только при появлении персистентности / появлении слоя БД?
- Как поступать, если у сущности более двух полей уникальны? (пример, возможно не лучший: сущность "юридическое лицо", поля "полное наименование юр. лица", "сокращённое наименование юрлица" и "ИНН" должны быть уникальными)

Update Перечитав статью [Entity vs Value Object: полный список отличий](https://habrahabr.ru/post/275599/) в части "типы эквивалентности"  наверное есть смысл уточнить, что Brand – это полноценная сущность, а не Value Object:

```
public class Brand
{
    public Brand(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Уникальность на уровне домена - нормальное предметное ограничение. Например, организация с одинаковыми ИНН\КПП должна быть одна, чтобы не смущать пользователей и чтобы искать по ней можно было. БД тут не при чём. По остальному сам не уверен как лучше, подождём ответов.

Comment: `Правда, в этом случае так же есть проблемы: непонятно, как быть если у нас должно быть два и более уникальных полей на одном объекте.` в этом случае можно хранить в двух Dictionary. Но смысл уникальности именно не относительно объекта а относительно хранилища, сам объект не может поддерживать свою уникальность.

Comment: Уникальность по сути это уже свойство хранилища, сам объект это оболочка + данные внутри, но сам по себе он не имеет информации о том как его хранить.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин уникальность в плане ключа таблицы - да, свойство хранилища. Уникальность в предметной области - нет, свойство сущности.

Comment: @Monk да, просто обычно предполагается что в доменной модели храняться только данные "объектов" но не другая информация, и часто в красивом коде предполагается что один объект хранит только одну какую-то логику, задачу. Я не спорю, сам пытаюсь понять, в процессе общения. По этой идее метаданные того как должен храниться объект вообще не должны в нём хранится... хотя я с этим не могу однозначно согласиться. Так как если он хранит и метаданные, значит он уже выполняет две задачи.

Comment: Это называется правило единственной ответственности. Хотя как говорил выше пока не могу однозначно с этим согласиться.

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но если у объекта должны быть уникальные поля в пределах некой "коллекции", то не поможет ли использование HashSet<T> в качестве этой самой "коллекции" и переопределением методов Equals и GetHash в сущности?

Answer (score 0):

Пересматривая один из своих любимых репозиториев с [примером проекта построенного на базе DDD подхода](https://github.com/EduardoPires/EquinoxProject/), кажется понял в какой стороне искать правильный ответ.

Краткий пересказ issue [Unique customer name validation](https://github.com/EduardoPires/EquinoxProject/issues/33)

Подобного рода проверку нельзя делать при помощи Validator'а в доменном слое.

Необходимо при создании своей сущности сделать вызов репозитория на предмет "есть ли уже такой экземпляр".